# UnicodeEncodeError when extract text from PDF in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the content from PDF file and store it in text file.
my code works fine when for page 1 in my PDF file(pdfreader.getPage(0)), but when I do it for page 2, I got an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 1831: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I am not sure what does this mean since I am new to Python, and my code is:

```
import PyPDF2
pdffileobj=open('meetingminutes.pdf','rb')
pdfreader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffileobj)
pageobj=pdfreader.getPage(1)

content=pageobj.extractText()
file=open('pdftotext.txt','w')
file.write(str(content))
file.close()
```

Comment: `str(content, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Is this python2 or python3?

Comment: I use python3 for the coding

Comment: Python3 should be natively utf-8. GBK is Chinese encoding? '\u2122' is the UTF-16 code for a trademark symbol, which would fit with Chinese encoding. Start with changing the script header to `# coding=utf-16` (see [Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#id8)).

Comment: i didn't see any Chinese in my PDF file.

Comment: You may not have. PyPDF2 did. It saw what it thought was a utf-16 code for a trademark and assumed it was reading Chinese.

Comment: Hence the "'gbk' codec" comment in the error. [GBK is an extension of the GB2312 character set for simplified Chinese characters ... GBK has been extended by Microsoft in Code page 936/1386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)).

Comment: ok, got it. those code issues are really so confusing

Comment: Yes, especially when talking about something simple like the little trademark symbol you see everywhere [trademark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm). It should be identifying it as "e284a2" which is the utf-8 code for the trademark.

Comment: Do you know which line has the error? Is it in reading the PDF or writing out the string? If it's the writing part, you could try `str(content, encoding='utf-16')`

Comment: it is write out part, I check variable content, and I can see it in shell and the text in it:  type(content) <class 'str'>, so we I try str(content, encoding='utf-16'), it returns TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: My mistake - the encoding belongs with the open.`file=open('pdftotext.txt','w', encoding="utf-16")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172923/discussion-between-alan-and-frank).

Comment: file=open('pdftotext.txt','w', encoding="utf-16") : this make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: `file=open('pdftotext.txt','w', encoding="utf-16")`

PyPDF2 is reading one or more elements on the page as UTF-16 (instead of UTF-8 or ASCII) and assuming this means there is Chinese text present. When you try and write a string in Python3, it defaults to UTF-8. This will fail as there is a UTF-16 character present in the string.

'gbk' is Chinese encoding. [GBK is an extension of the GB2312 character set for simplified Chinese characters ... GBK has been extended by Microsoft in Code page 936/1386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)).

'\u2122' is the UTF-16 code for a [trademark symbol](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm). Not sure why PyPDF2 is using the UTF-16 code and not the UTF-8 identifier. You could in theory do a replace on the string and down-convert it to the correct UTF-8 identifier ("e284a2") or even just to "TM".

You could tell Python to treat everything in the script as UTF-16 by adding a coding header to the script (see [PEP 263 Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#id8)):

```
# coding=utf-16
import PyPDF2
```

The easiest solution though is to change the encoding on the output:

```
file=open('pdftotext.txt','w', encoding="utf-16")
```